# ASP.NET MVC view won't update after model changes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controller, .net-6.0, viewmodel

The Radiologists view loads just fine first time you enter, and the dropdown is filled with data.

After you select a doctor, the table should display the two values shown in the view, but they won't update, still showing as "" and 0.

I've tried `Modelstate.Clear()` to no avail.

My view (in a very alpha stage):

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> ViewLocalizer
@model RadiologistModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = ViewLocalizer["Page.Radiologists.Title"];
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h1>@ViewLocalizer["Page.Radiologists.Title"]</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Users,
            new SelectList(Model.Users, "Usuarioid", "NombreApellidos", Model.Users.First().Usuarioid),
            new 
            { 
                style = "width: 250px;"
            })

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Aparcar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>@Model.rad.UsuarioNombre</td>
                    <td>@Model.rad.CantidadPruebasAparcar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

View model:

```
public class RadiologistModel
{
    public ICollection<UsuarioDTO> Users { get; set; }
    public RadiologoAparcarDTO rad { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace xxx
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Radiologists controller
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    public class RadiologistsController : BaseController
    {
        public RadiologistsController(IRISAPI_Client client, IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> stringLocalizer) : base(client, stringLocalizer)
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var identity = User.Identity;

            if (identity != null) 
            {
                var authToken = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Authentication)?.Value;

                if (authToken != null) 
                {
                    _client.SetBearerToken(authToken);
                    var radiologistModel = new RadiologistModel
                    {
                        Users = await _client.UsuariosAllAsync(),
                        rad = new RadiologoAparcarDTO()
                    };

                    return View(radiologistModel);
                }
            }            

            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> AparcarGET(int usuarioId)
        {
            RadiologistModel rad;
            var authToken = User.Identity.GetAuthToken();

            if (authToken != null) 
            {
                _client.SetBearerToken(authToken);
                var aparcar = await _client.AparcarGETAsync(usuarioId);
                ModelState.Clear();

                rad = new RadiologistModel
                {
                    Users = await _client.UsuariosAllAsync(),
                    rad = aparcar
                };

                return View(rad);
            }

            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> AparcarPUTAsync(int usuarioId, int cantidadPruebasAparcar)
        {
            var authToken = User.Identity.GetAuthToken();

            if (authToken != null)
            {
                _client.SetBearerToken(authToken);
                var rad2 = new GuardarRadiologoAparcarDTO
                {
                    CantidadPruebasAparcar = cantidadPruebasAparcar
                };

                await _client.AparcarPUTAsync(usuarioId, rad2);

                return View("Success");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#Users").on('change', function () {

    var userId = $('#Users').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Radiologists/AparcarGET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { usuarioId: userId },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert('oops something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that the AparcarGET controller method is indeed being called on ddl onchange (as breakpoints are being hit) and the values are being stored in view model correctly.

Edit 2: Javascript Error 500

I've just detected a jQuery 500 error in the console after return View(model), but don't know the reason yet.

Edit 3: Launch on Firefox.

This is what firefox has to say regarding the 500 error: `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`? The controller is in the same origin, nothing changed!

[image]

[image: Javascript Error 500]

Edit 4: Following @hatem87 advice

It's true that at first I made a mistake and I was following a POST request to a GET method, but changing the request to GET as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Radiologists/AparcarGET",
```

nothing changes, as the error is still the same.

I've also tried enabling cors in Startup.cs

```
services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

just in case it's a CORS problem, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a POST call to a GET method.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Radiologists/AparcarGET",
```

A controller method is by default a Http Get.
You may change the client side call to use a Get request which make more sense because you are not changing any state in the backend in this call, or change in the Controller by annotating the method by [HttpPost].

I have a doubt also about returning **View** in this method, may be you need only a **PartialView** to be returned, this is will avoid displaying the common layout of the application.

500 error comes most of the time from backend issue. Try to debug the backend code (controller) to check if the code arrives where you want or not.